# KarateUI - Finding inputs by placeholder attribute

Tags: karate

I've been having trouble around finding elements by attribute/property.  Following UI visible example:

```
<input tabindex="0" placeholder="www.stuff.com/example" type="text" id="sub-selector-37" class="form-control" value="">
```

The unique piece is the placeholder text.

I've tried the following:

```
And waitFor('input[placeholder=www.stuff.com/example]')  - Error
And waitFor('input[placeholder="www.stuff.com/example"]') - Error
And waitFor('input[placeholder='www.stuff.com/example']') Finds nothing
```

Also tried a more direct input approach:

```
Then waitFor('{}Something else')
Then input('input[placeholder=www.stuff.com/example']', 'Stuff')
```

I'm hoping this is just good old PEBKAC on my part. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, use double-quotes and nest single-quotes:

```
And waitFor("input[placeholder='www.stuff.com/example']")
```

A tip: use the debugger and you can experiment with things like `highlightAll('input')` and narrow down what works: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1252817691963830272

Comment: That solved the issue. Thank you!   Im wondering how the highlight would assist for finding issues such as I had. I'll dig in a bit more.

Comment: For my (and colleagues) knowledge. How do we identify what needs single, double, or no quotes at all?

Comment: @Puti both are supported in JavaScript. single suffices most of the time. this is a case where you had to specify a string within a string :) so use double for the outer. does that make sense ?